# Facebook Graph Api v 2.4

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Facebook released a new version of its well-known graph api, and I think that the documentation provided by https://developers.facebook.com/ is quiet confusing. I'm actually working on an app that will need a facebook connection; therefore I would like to have some proper, let's say more straight forward, help or guidance. 
I already tried a couple of things but it seems that I'm trying it the wrong way.

```
AccessToken accessToken = intent.getExtras().getParcelable("aaaa");
        new GraphRequest(accessToken,"/{id,birthday",null,
                HttpMethod.GET,
                new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                    public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                        Log.d("aaaa",response.toString());
                    }
                }
        ).executeAsync();
```

I hope that someone will help me, and provide me some advices.

Comment: Isn't it helpful: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/v2.4

Comment: Well I already passed through that " login facebook " getting started , but after that , it was confusing for me to access the data of the profile , i tried the profile class with its getters but it provide only a restricted amount of data

Comment: what do you specifically want to access?

Comment: I want to access the user pages , birthday , some profile pictures . i already specified the required permissions

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
AccessToken accessToken = intent.getExtras().getParcelable("aaaa");
        new GraphRequest(accessToken,"/me?fields=id,birthday",null,
                HttpMethod.GET,
                new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                    public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                        Log.d("aaaa",response.toString());
                    }
                }
        ).executeAsync();
```

Comment: I've tried it and it brings me this : {Response:  responseCode: 400, graphObject: null, error: {HttpStatus: 400, errorCode: 2500, errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.}}

Comment: well, you need to use a user token, of course. make sure you got an active one, with user login and whatnot.

Answer (score 0):

Well ! Best solution that i have found so far is that:

1. Go to  [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) and request for `/v2.4/me/` or `v2.4/userIdForWhichYouWantToAccessData`
2. Start adding fields from left pane which you want to get.
3. When you are done, submit the query and then copy the query string and use it with `new GraphRequest()`.

I hope its helpful :)